# C++ copy only needed header file for dll from separate project

Tags: c++, dll, dependencies, header-files

My C++ project is dependent on a huge project. My project uses many dll's from huge project. It take about few hours to install the huge project and I want to remove the need to install the huge project for someone else.

After research I understand there is two methods to compile and link using dll 1) Using a lib and header. 
2) Using loadlibary method.

In loadlibrary method I need to know exactly the methods needed to load. Since I don't know this I went with option 1. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Currently I have included the path to the big project in the compiler additional dependencies configuration option. I want to share the included header with my team. The big project has lot of headers that is not used by my dependency dlls. I tried copying all the headers but some .cpp are directly used without any headers.

**Is there any way I can copy only the header files needed from the huge project?** Possibly automatically using less manual work. Currently the headers and cpp are about 1gb which I can't share via github. If I can't copy the headers is there anyway I could automatically generate all the dependency definitions to a file and use it? Please let me know whats the standard way of handling situations like this.

Comment: Shouldn't your build system/compiler automatically track headers? If you're using CMake, this should be tracked. A makefile, you should be able to list the included headers via `gcc -E`.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically build and link to the library (dll).

To do so, you need to

- include the folder containing the .h files with the compiler -I argument `-IC:\path\`
- link to the folder including the dll with the linker -L argument `-LC:\path\`

The lib has to be compiled with the same compiler & same platform